How to open / save an excel file with Python
I am using a PDF to Excel converter where I scrape some values from the spreadsheet once converted. However, an error occurs when I try and paste this to another spreadsheet:

source files contain some invalid XML

I am using Openpyxl and not Pandas.
If I manually open and save the Excel file prior to running the Python code, it works fine.
import os
import openpyxl as xl
from openpyxl import formatting, styles, Workbook

from datetime import datetime
import xlwt
from parDict import parsDict

# Open source file
inFolder = "....path to files"

outFile = ("...path to Data Database.xlsx")


# Function to append to database excel sheet
def appendDatabase():
    # Open destination file
 

    wb2 = xl.load_workbook(outFile)
    ws2 = wb2.active   

    # Append new data
    ......
    # Save the workbook
    wb2.save(outFile)

### Functions to scrape data
def.....()
def....()



### To open and save excel file initially - Trying to replicate opening, saving and closing of excel file**
# for inFile in os.listdir(inFolder):
#     f = os.path.join(inFolder, inFile)
#     print(f)
#     wb1 = xl.load_workbook(f)
#     ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]
#     wb1.save(f)

for inFile in os.listdir(inFolder):
    f = os.path.join(inFolder, inFile)   
    wb1 = xl.load_workbook(f)
    ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]
    
   execute all functions...

However, the code throws an error.
Is there a way to code so that I don't have to manually save?

Please [edit] your question to include a [mre]. Opening and saving an Excel file with openpyxl is different to opening the file with MS Excel. It might be easier to address the problem at data extraction. This answer might help.

What doesn't run? Note also, Opening an Excel file in Openpyxl and saving it and opening an Excel file in Excel and saving it are two different things. Openpyxl does not use Excel. So if the Excel app is 'fixing' the file then Openpyxl probably won't help. Use a module that does use Excel like Xlwings or Win32com.

if you have got your data, maybe you can use 'pandas' to convert your data as DataFrame, and save them by pd.to_excel.

Without much information it is quite hard to understand exactly what is going wrong.
However, a potential workaround would be to save the file as a csv rather than Excel.
First, check if you get any errors trying to read the Excel file back into pandas (which I assume you're using) without errors.
df = pd.read_excel("your_excel_file.xlsx")

Then
df.to_csv("your_csv_file.csv", encoding="utf-8")

Putting the utf8 part in just in case there is an encoding error.
You may also need to install openpyxl for reading the Excel in pandas.

Try using the openpyxl or pandas library to save the excel file.
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('file.xlsx')
wb.save('file.xlsx')
wb.close()
OR
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')
df.to_excel('file.xlsx', index=False)

wb.close() does nothing unless you are using the 'read_only' flag.
